# gatling on gradle: NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Serializable

Tags: gradle, gatling

Following a couple of online tutorials, I am trying to include some load testing in my gradle build. I am getting this error when executing gradle loadTest. I use Java 12 (sourceCompatibility 11 configured in build.gradle)

Relevant plugins:

```
apply plugin: "scala"
implementation('org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.13.0')
testCompile("io.gatling.highcharts:gatling-charts-highcharts:3.2.1")
```

gradle task:

```
task loadTest(type: JavaExec) {
  dependsOn testClasses
  description = "load test with Gatling"
  group = "Load Test"
  classpath = sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath
  main = "io.gatling.app.Gatling"
  args = [
          "--simulation", "com.skios.ms.authentication.test.MainSimulation",
          "--results-folder", "${buildDir}/gatling-results",
          "--bodies-folder", sourceSets.test.resources.srcDirs.toList().first().toString() + "/gatling/bodies",
  ]
}
```

Test class:

```
package com.skios.ms.authentication.test

import scala.language.postfixOps
import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.http.Predef._

import scala.concurrent.duration._

class MainSimulation extends Simulation {

  val httpConf = http.baseUrl("https://MYAPI.COM/api/v1") 
  val scn = scenario("Sample")
    .exec(http("request1")
      .get("/authentication/get-token"))
    .pause(100)
  setUp(scn.inject(rampUsers(20) during (5 seconds)).protocols(httpConf))
}
```

gradle result:

```
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

> Task :compileTestScala

Pruning sources from previous analysis, due to incompatible CompileSetup.

> Task :loadTest FAILED
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Serializable
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
        at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:151)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:802)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:700)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:623)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        at com.typesafe.scalalogging.StrictLogging.$init$(Logging.scala:39)
        at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.<init>(Gatling.scala:35)
        at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.<clinit>(Gatling.scala)
        at io.gatling.app.Gatling.main(Gatling.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Serializable
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        ... 13 more

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':loadTest'.
> Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-12.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 21s
5 actionable tasks: 5 executed
```

I have no Scala experience so I'm pretty lost. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Gatling doesn't support 2.13.x version of scala. Changing it to 2.12.10 fixed the error for me.

Your build.gradle
`implementation('org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.13.0')`

Working version for me `implementation('org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.12.10')`

This is Gatling documentation where the version dependency is called out
https://gatling.io/docs/current/installation/#scala-version