# Error: Unable to initialize main class (...) Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Serializable

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, gradle, noclassdeffounderror

I am practicing Scala and try to run external project, which includes Spark and Gradle. Unfortunately, I am getting this error all the time:

[image]

I would be grateful for any advice that can help with fixing this issue. I am using Scala 2.13.12.

I've tried to change the Java and Scala versions, modified dependencies in build.gradle, checked if environmental variables are included.

Comment: Maybe this other link can help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57817714/gatling-on-gradle-noclassdeffounderror-scala-serializable